# Generating a random numbers and letters

Tags: php

Can I ask for a certain code on how to generate a random letters and numbers in one word. I know there's a PHP function rand(), but I don't know if it's also applicable with letters. There's also a function called mt_rand() but I don't know how it works. I'm planning on generating a word like this one:

```
$randomcode = re784dfg7ert7;
```

Do you guys have any simple code on this one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to use [`Random::alphanumericLowercaseString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random), or even drop the “lowercase” requirement as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a more extensive method that I use constantly to generate random numbers, letters or mixed:

```
function assign_rand_value($num) {

    // accepts 1 - 36
    switch($num) {
        case "1"  : $rand_value = "a"; break;
        case "2"  : $rand_value = "b"; break;
        case "3"  : $rand_value = "c"; break;
        case "4"  : $rand_value = "d"; break;
        case "5"  : $rand_value = "e"; break;
        case "6"  : $rand_value = "f"; break;
        case "7"  : $rand_value = "g"; break;
        case "8"  : $rand_value = "h"; break;
        case "9"  : $rand_value = "i"; break;
        case "10" : $rand_value = "j"; break;
        case "11" : $rand_value = "k"; break;
        case "12" : $rand_value = "l"; break;
        case "13" : $rand_value = "m"; break;
        case "14" : $rand_value = "n"; break;
        case "15" : $rand_value = "o"; break;
        case "16" : $rand_value = "p"; break;
        case "17" : $rand_value = "q"; break;
        case "18" : $rand_value = "r"; break;
        case "19" : $rand_value = "s"; break;
        case "20" : $rand_value = "t"; break;
        case "21" : $rand_value = "u"; break;
        case "22" : $rand_value = "v"; break;
        case "23" : $rand_value = "w"; break;
        case "24" : $rand_value = "x"; break;
        case "25" : $rand_value = "y"; break;
        case "26" : $rand_value = "z"; break;
        case "27" : $rand_value = "0"; break;
        case "28" : $rand_value = "1"; break;
        case "29" : $rand_value = "2"; break;
        case "30" : $rand_value = "3"; break;
        case "31" : $rand_value = "4"; break;
        case "32" : $rand_value = "5"; break;
        case "33" : $rand_value = "6"; break;
        case "34" : $rand_value = "7"; break;
        case "35" : $rand_value = "8"; break;
        case "36" : $rand_value = "9"; break;
    }
    return $rand_value;
}

function get_rand_alphanumeric($length) {
    if ($length>0) {
        $rand_id="";
        for ($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++) {
            mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
            $num = mt_rand(1,36);
            $rand_id .= assign_rand_value($num);
        }
    }
    return $rand_id;
}

function get_rand_numbers($length) {
    if ($length>0) {
        $rand_id="";
        for($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++) {
            mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
            $num = mt_rand(27,36);
            $rand_id .= assign_rand_value($num);
        }
    }
    return $rand_id;
}

function get_rand_letters($length) {
    if ($length>0) {
        $rand_id="";
        for($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++) {
            mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
            $num = mt_rand(1,26);
            $rand_id .= assign_rand_value($num);
        }
    }
    return $rand_id;
}
```

---

**USAGE:**

Basically I have a main function with the array, then I call secondary functions to build my string based on the length parameter:

***Letters:***

```
$str = get_rand_letters(8); // Only Letters
```

***Numbers:***

```
$str = get_rand_numbers(8); // Only Numbers
```

***AlphaNumeric:***

```
$str = get_rand_alphanumeric(8); // Numbers and Letters
```

This Question is answered by **Kerrek SB**, but this may help someone searching for a more extensive and flexible way.

Comment: This really isn't "extensive." It's just wordy. You could stuff all those letters and numbers into arrays and reference them by numeric key. `assign_rand_values()` seems kind of unnecessary. Also, seeding with a predictable number like `microtime()` isn't always the best idea. (Sorry if I sound like a jerk, I'm just trying to be helpful :) )

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: nor a jerk, an individual conserned with my performance :)  Truly I've setup this a long time ago, and based on some example... it worked and I never looked at it again! But, I'll make does performance improvements! Tks :)

Comment: You should seed the RNG *once* per program, not every time in the loop, otherwise you don't get predictable statistical properties.

Comment: This answer reminds me why I avoid `switch` blocks as much as possible -- they are super verbose.  I'd be converting it to a clean and simple lookup array.  `if ($length>0) {` is either an unnecessary check or going to be guilty of preventing the declaration of an expected variable.

Answer (score 20):

```
<?php
echo substr(sha1(mt_rand()),17,6); //To Generate Random Numbers with Letters.
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: Create an alphabet, `$alph = "0123456789abcde...";`.

Step 2: Create a random number, `$n = rand(0, ALPHSIZE-1);`, or use `mt_rand()`.

Step 3: Get the appropriate index in the alphabet: `$alph[n];`

Rinse and repeat steps 2 and 3 for as many times as you need characters.

<s>If you want strong statistical properties (like uniformness), you should work a little harder with the random number, but this should get you started.</s> (I think the statistical properties of that should be sufficient.)

---

OK, might as well spell it out:

```
$alph = "012...";
function make_random_string($N)
{
  $s = "";
  for ($i = 0; $i != $N; ++$i)
    s .= $alph[mt_rand(0, ALPHSIZE - 1)];
  return $s;
}
```

And here's the version that takes a custom alphabet:

```
function make_random_custom_string($N, $alphabet)
{
  $s = "";
  for ($i = 0; $i != $N; ++$i)
    s .= $alphabet[mt_rand(0, strlen($alphabet) - 1)];
  return $s;
}
```

Example: 10 random odd digits: `make_random_custom_string(10, "13579");`

Comment: `rand() % N` will prefer characters closer to the beginning of the alphabet, unless the maximum random value plus one is evenly divisible by the size of the alphabet.  `rand(0, strlen($alph) - 1)` would be better.

Comment: @cdhowie: yes yes I know... as I said, if uniformity is important, you have to work a bit harder. The `mt_rand()` function seems to get you the correct distribution, though. --- Oh, I see, you can actually specify a range for `rand()` as well. I'll edit!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get the step 3. Can you be more clear or make your statement like teaching a noob programmer? Thanks.

Comment: @Glove: You have to get a number in the range 0..SIZE-1, so I just took the remainder after division by that size (`%` is "modulo"). But never mind, there's a better way by specifying the range directly in the rand-call, do that instead. This will give you one character at a time, so loop for as many characters as you need.

Comment: Ok thanks for the revision of your answer. One last question! How do I get the ALPHSIZE? Did you declare it as a variable or something? Sorry if I kinda misinterpret your answer.

Comment: @glove: It's just the number of symbols in your alphabet. You could use `strlen($alph)`, or just use the actual number, since I assume you know how many characters you are using. You could even make the alphabet a parameter of the function so that you can pick a different set of characters for different purposes...

Comment: I know it's probably an insignificant micro-optimization, but I would store `strlen($alphabet) - 1` in a variable. It seems unnecessary to call it so many times when it will never change during the for loop.

Comment: Thanks man! But why is it sometimes an apostrophe appears in a string?  How can I remove it?

Answer (score 5):

Use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

```
$desired_length = 10; //or whatever length you want
$unique = uniqid();

$your_random_word = substr($unique, 0, $desired_length);
```

Comment: Set `more_entropy` (second argument - first being an empty string for the prefix) to true to output 23 characters instead of 13.

Comment: This can also contain `.`

Answer (score 3):

This was an easy way for me- this generates a 15 character string -

```
        $alph = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $code='';

        for($i=0;$i<15;$i++){
           $code .= $alph[rand(0, 35)];
        }
```

Comment: Why not `for()` loop syntax? Why not concatenate with `.=`? Why not access the random character by its offset (`$code .= $alph[rand(0, 35)];`) instead of those iterated function calls?  If I was going to implement your logic, only the first two lines would be the same.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, the code sample is updated.

Answer (score 2):

It might be done this way:

```
function RandomCode($length = 10)
{
    $code = '';
    $total = 0;

    do
    {
        if (rand(0, 1) == 0)
        {
            $code.= chr(rand(97, 122)); // ASCII code from **a(97)** to **z(122)**
        }
        else
        {
            $code.= rand(0, 9); // Numbers!!
        }
        $total++;
    } while ($total < $length);

    return $code;
}
```

Comment: Look into `mt_rand()`. It also might be a good idea to limit your usage of it (or rand()) by creating a random number between 97 and 132. Then use char if the number is 122 or less or subtract 122 and interpret it as a number if it is great than 122.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I always used rand function, but I see that mt_rand is faster. But if a use mt_rand giving min and max parameters instead of verifying if number if more ou less 122 ?

Comment: I got it, so you have just one mt_rand, not two like in my code. Very nice!

Comment: It could also be expanded to include capital letters and special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
$numLenth = 35;

function make_seed_Token() {
  list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
  return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
}

srand(make_seed_Token());

$numSeed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$getNumber = "";
for($i = 0; $i < $numLenth; $i ++) {
 $getNumber .= $numSeed[rand(0, strlen($numSeed))];

}

echo $getNumber;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: `$numSeed` does not change in length in your snippet, so it is unnecessary effort for php to count its length over and over.

Answer (score 1):

What about this simple code.
This will generate 10 characters,you can limit characters by modifying the limits (0,10)

```
$str = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10);
echo $str; //7aca159655
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

```
function randText($len=4){
    $str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
        $txt.=substr($str, rand(0, strlen($str)), 1);   
    }
return $txt;
}
```

to use simply type:

```
$yourVar = randText(10);  // to get 10char long text
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: `substr()` is an unnecessary call when intending to access a single, single-byte character.  Most simply, use bracket syntax to target the character by its offset.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a PHP class for generating random numbers and strings [PHPRandomValue](https://github.com/ejfrancis/PHPRandomValue),

It uses "mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)"  to generate random numbers and values. I made it while working on a crypto project because I needed a safe random value generator and mt_rand() doesn't meet that requirement. Here's an example usage

```
$randomValue = new RandomValue;

$randomValue->randomNumber(): = -3880998

$randomValue->randomNumberBetween(1,10): = 2

$randomValue->randomTextString(): = CfCkKDHRgUULdGWcSqP4

$randomValue->randomTextString(10):  = LorPIxaeEY

$randomValue->randomKey(): = C7al8tX9.gqYLf2ImVt/!$NOY79T5sNCT/6Q.$!.6Gf/Q5zpa3

$randomValue->randomKey(10):  = RDV.dc6Ai/
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this with full control:

```
<?php
$str = 'QaR0SbT1UcV2WdX3YeZ4f5g6h7i8j9kAlBmCnDoEpFqGrHsItJuKvLwMxNyOzP';
// a-z 0-9 A-Z in above string

$shuffled = str_shuffle($str);

$shuffled = substr($shuffled,1,30);

echo $shuffled;
?>
```

Change $str according to your needs. I used small alphabets a to z, capital alphabets A to Z and numeric values 0 to 9.

Comment: That's a really hacky solution and will result in a huge bias and loss of entropy on the resulting "random" string.

Comment: This doesn't offer double digit values, it gives `1` thirteen opportunities to be selected.  This answer is only going to mislead researchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
// A string with random letters and numbers. A-Z, a-z, 0-9


// A function in PHP is a block of code that can be used elsewhere in code.
// This function is called rand_string and will generate a random sequence of characters in one string.
// A default value of 16 characters is set, so that if no integer is supplied it will use the value of 16.
function rand_string($length = 16) {

    // A string is something that holds alphanumeric characters and other symbols. 
    // This string is an empty one, or at least that's how it starts.
    $string = '';

    // This is known as a for/next loop, it's will run a section of code for a set number of times.
    // A counter $i is incremented on each pass. In this case until it has operated $length number of times.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        // This variable ($die) is assigned a random number - which is obtained via the PHP function mt_rand.
        //Consult the PHP docs for more information.
        $die = mt_rand(1, 3);

        // This switch statement picks a case that is true and runs the accompanying code as defined in each case.
        switch ($die) {

            // This case will be activated if the variable $die has the value of 1. And case 2 if it has the value of 2 and so on.
            case 1:
                // Here and subsequently a random value between 48 and 57 is assigned to the $rnd variable.
                $rnd = mt_rand(48, 57);
                break;

            case 2:
                $rnd = mt_rand(65, 90);
                break;

            case 3:
                $rnd = mt_rand(97, 122);
                break;
        }

        // This is another variable $string which is assigned the ASCII character that is represented by the $rnd variable.
        // ASCII characters are codes that computers use to represent characters and symbols.
        // The chr function is a special PHP function that returns the character represented by the ASCII code.
        // In this case the value of $rnd.
        $string .= chr($rnd);
    }

    // Here we reach the final result. The value of $string is returned to source of the function call.
    return $string;
}

// Segments of the function, loops and switches are enclosed between curly brackets {}. This limits the scope of the processing contained within.

// Usage of this function to obtain a 10 character random string.
// echo is a function that prints the result to the browser/screen.
$mystring = rand_string(10);
echo $mystring;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create random alpha num string based on variable chars:

```
function createRandomCode() 
{     
    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";     
    srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);     

    $i = 0;     
    $pass = '';  

    while ($i <= 7) 
    {         
        $num = rand() % 33;         
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);         
        $pass = $pass . $tmp;         
        $i++;     
    }    

    return $pass; 
}
```

Use this function as `$random = createRandomCode();`

Comment: More concisely written as https://3v4l.org/r1CuO  Your answer could benefit from an edit which explains how your snippet works AND why you elected to write it with the functions/techniques that you did.