# php function to generate numbers and letters

Tags: php, function, random

So I need to create a function that will produce the following types of combinations:

- Option #1: ### (can/needs to be 3 numbers)
- Option #2: #*# (number,    letter, number)
- Option #3: #** (number, letter, letter)
- Option #4: **# (letter, letter, number)
- Option #5: *## (letter, number, number)
- Option #6: *** (letter, letter, letter)

The reason for this is to parse those possibilities against the FAA website to find the available codes. So if I can get the function created to create those possibilities, I can store them in a database and then write my function to loop over those, and push them to a curl method to scrape the response. I'm code blocked on how to create this function though

**As an example:**

`Field 1: 123  -  Field 2: 1B1  -  Field 3: T8C`

Comment: what have you tried yourself so far? We're not here to write your code for you, but rather to help you when you're stuck. So show us what you've tried, and we'll attempt to help you.

Comment: I've tried some of the examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322689/generating-a-random-numbers-and-letters but couldn't get them to do what I needed.

Comment: You want the list of existing FAA codes as of today? http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/lid/lidhme.htm

Comment: This is where I'm actually trying to post those combinations to: http://aircraft.faa.gov/E.Gov/NN/reserve.aspx

Comment: Well, then you're looing for permutations/combinations. Common math packages normally contain this, all you need is to read some documentation or search for the existing questions. http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to do this is to simply add all characters to an array, loop over it 3x and just add em all together. Like so:

```
function return_all_possible_combos() {
   $chars = array();
   for($i=48;$i<=57;$i++) {
      $chars[] = chr($i); // adds the characters 0-9 to the $chars array (48-57 are the positions of 0-9 in the ASCII table
   }
   for($i=65;$i<=90;$i++) {
      $chars[] = chr($i); // adds the characters 0-9 to the $chars array (65-90 are the positions of A-Z in the ASCII table
   }

   // $chars now holds all values 0-9 and A-Z

   $possible_values = array();
   foreach($chars as $k=>$first_char) {
      foreach($chars as $l=>$second_char) {
         foreach($chars as $m=>$third_char) {
            $possible_values[] = $first_char . $second_char . $third_char;
         }
      }
   }
   return $possible_values;
}
```

Comment: That seems to have done it! Looking over the list - seems like it's produced what I needed. It is an interesting approach as well. Not how I would have done it. But definitely seems to produce the results.

Comment: With more permutations I'd go for a recursive approach, but since there are only 3 and this way is easier to read for the average person... this is the way I went

Comment: Truly appreciate it. It does seem to produce the results and combinations I was looking for. Some 46K of them :)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is quite trivial, you might use something like this:

```
<?
function randomString($format) {
  $format = str_split($format);

  $chars = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

  $res = "";

  foreach ($format as $f) {
    if ($f=="#") $res .= rand(0,9);
    else $res .= $chars[array_rand($chars)];
  }

  return $res;

}

?>
```

This basically returns random string the way you need it. For example:

```
<?
  echo randomString("##**");
?>
```

Will return two numbers followed by two characters.

I wrote this without testing, so it might need a little tweaking, and I usually do not prefer writing code for other people problems, but this seemed like interesting, albeit trivial problem.

Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: If the goal is to get a complete set of codes, random probably isn't the way to go. Though I suppose given enough time, you will eventually hit all the different combinations.

Comment: Well I did not want to get into the purpose of the random string, but you are right. Especially because he is guessing randomly. If he needs to guess he should start from first and go to the last, not guess randomly since nobody can guarantee that same random sequence will not be generated twice or even more.