# Random generate numbers and letters based on 2 symbols as letters and numbers and using a -

Tags: vb.net

This is a number #
This is a number or letter?

Separate the random string like ??#?#-???##-#?#???-#???#-##

I need some code that generates the string as shown above. It doesn't have to be complicated.

Expected result example: 2F421-QD421-2W3FY0-3F4L1-37

I've tried using PHP and this example but wasn't able to achieve what I was looking for [Generating a random numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322689/generating-a-random-numbers-and-letters)

I am looking for a vb.net project to handle the generation so i can submit the serial into a database manually.

Comment: Please post your code?

Comment: It's quite typical with codes like `2F421-QD421-2W3FY0-3F4L1-37` that there is a checksum involved to validate the number. Did you need anything like that?

Comment: Basically I am needing to generate a large list of whats above so I can input it into a database, because I dont know how to do that its easier to just do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I quite like this approach:

```
Dim characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Dim template = "??#?#-???##-#?#???-#???#-##"

Dim rnd = New Random()

Dim query =
    From t In template
    Select If(t = "-", "-", characters(rnd.Next(If(t = "?", characters.Length, 10))))

Dim result = String.Join("", query)

Console.WriteLine(result)
```

It gives me output like this:

> RC2C9-DHB47-1Q07RL-8BIF7-57

Comment: I like your approach but if i'm not mistaken ??? gave 7RL, did you change the string before posting the output?

Comment: @Devcon - Yes, the OP describes `?` as outputting "a number or letter".

Comment: oops i must use glasses i guess, thanks for your answer i can say i learned something today :)

Comment: Great code, very simple and effective.  I learned a couple things looking at it.

Comment: Can you provide the project please so i may look at it thank you.

Comment: @GEGeek - Sorry, what project?

Comment: Sorry I meant can you please provide a sample project with the code used in a form that generates the above, also whats to prevent the output from being generated twice, don't need the same serial outputting twice.

Comment: @GEGeek - I ran the above code in LINQPad. There's no project. Just copy and paste into a Console App if you like.

Comment: @GEGeek - There's nothing preventing duplicates (except that they are exceptionally unlikely). You didn't say that this was a requirement before?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 functions 1 for letters GRL (Generate Random Letter) 1 for numbers GRN (Generate Random Number) like so:
Result of what i called is: W96-GKlF6

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Console.WriteLine(GRL(1) + GRN(2) + "-" + GRL(4) + GRN(1))
End Sub

Public Function GRL(ByRef iLength As Integer) As String
    Static rdm As New Random()
    Dim allowChrs() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
    Dim sResult As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = 0 To iLength - 1
        sResult += allowChrs(rdm.Next(0, allowChrs.Length))
    Next

    Return sResult
End Function

Public Function GRN(ByRef iLength As Integer) As String
    Static rdm As New Random()
    Dim allowChrs() As Char = "0123456789".ToCharArray()
    Dim sResult As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = 0 To iLength - 1
        sResult += allowChrs(rdm.Next(0, allowChrs.Length))
    Next

    Return sResult
End Function
```

Comment: Can you provide the project please.

Comment: how do you want that?

Comment: well i uploaded that to wetransfer, please mark as answer if i helped :) we.tl/t-5N2D3CL1Ep

Comment: How do i see the result, I just see an empty form when run.

Comment: If you want a message, replace `console.writeline` with `msgbox`

Comment: Or create a textbox and replace `console.writeline` with `textbox1.text = `, feel free to do whatever you like

Answer (score 0):

Easy, random numbers to use as ASCII codes, then check the position to delimit if its going to be just a number or a character that can be number or letter.

When is a position that can be number or letter, analyze the random number and split it. If the number is less than 11 that means is a number then add 47 and use the result as ASCII code (random create numbers from 1 to 36) so for example if the random is 1, we say 47 + 1 = 48,  48 is the ASCII code of 0.

If the number is 11 or more we add 54, so for example if random is 11 then we have 11 + 54 = 65.  65 is the ASCII code for the letter A.

```
    Dim Key As String = ""
    Dim N As Integer
    Randomize()
    For t = 1 To 23
        If t = 3 Or t = 5 Or t = 9 Or t = 10 Or t = 11 Or t = 13 Or t = 17 Or t >= 21 Then
            N = 10
        Else
            N = 36
        End If
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int(N * Rnd() + 1))
        If value < 11 Then
            Key = Key & Chr(value + 47)
        Else
            Key = Key & Chr(value + 54)
        End If
        If t = 5 Or t = 10 Or t = 16 Or t = 21 Then
            Key = Key & "-"
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: are you missing Randomize() function code or that for loop should be inside the function or what?

Comment: I used before the loop start, but it can be moved inside the loop in the line after the For t...